# Create Shapefile/Feature Class with CSV that has Shape values?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, shapefile, csv, feature-class

I have a CSV with no lat/long values, but it does have Shape.STArea and Shape.STLength values. Is there a way to make this CSV into a feature class or shapefile? This data is supposed to be a polygon.

[image]

I have access to ArcMap 10.4 or QGIS 2.18.3

Comment: No, no geometry, no shape.  There are an infinite number of geometries which share area and perimeter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To expand a little on Vince's comment, those two fields are just the numeric area of each polygon (in square meters or whatever units the layer was in) and its perimeter.

Whoever created that CSV may have had access to the geometry (the actual shapes) of the layer, but the CSV doesn't include it and therefore you can't recreate the layer from the CSV. You *can* store geometry in a table using a [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) field, but I'm guessing that CSV doesn't have that.